# Most cost and time efficient way to sound dampen exterior wall with drywall

Tags: drywall, sound-deadening

So in new construction here...

I want to sound deaden bedroom walls from outside noise.  Traffic, storms, loud people, etc.  I know I can't achieve 100% due to a window.  (I have plans to make a foam insert for that when desired for extra quiet-ness)  Ideally I would just do 1/2" drywall - green glue - 1/2" drywall.  If I do this, my premade window jambs will be about 1/4" short of reaching the plane of my drywall.  Is there a better way that does not require 1" to 1-1/8" thick drywall?

Answer (score 1):

Better insulation between the studs helps a lot. You've probably got or your builder is spec'ing fiberglass, which isn't great for sound dampening. Upgrade to mineral wool. Also, a layer of rigid foam or preferably mineral wool on the outside of the wall--covering the plywood or OSB sheathing--will help a lot too.

Better windows also help, if you haven't bought them yet. Triple pane makes a difference vs double-pane.

If everything is already built, then obviously all of those options are fairly disruptive, and increasing the thickness of the drywall on the interior side is a decent approach.

Answer (score 0):

I like @ilikedirt 's answer, but you could also do the following: 1) use a layer of Sound Deadening Board on the inside before installing the drywall, 2) use resilient channels installed horizontally on the inside for the drywall, 3) check for soffit vents along the wall, 4) check for electrical outlets or hose bibbs on the wall.

However, the biggest difference you can make is sealing up around the window.